# Remove Charcters From php form

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to strip certain characters and keywords from a php form and not having much luck.
What I want is to a modular filter list to remove urls and certain keywords. At the moment I just want to remove http links while keeping allowed domains. In this case example.com

```
<?php //Check whether the form has been submitted
 if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) {    
//Converts the new line characters (\n) in the text area into HTML line breaks (the <br /> tag)    
$_POST['Comments'] = nl2br($_POST['Comments']);     //Check whether a 
$_GET['Languages'] is set    
}

   //Let's now print out the received values in the browser   
 echo "<br />{$_POST['Comments']}<br /><br />"; 
} 
else 
{
    echo "You can't see this page without submitting the form."; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [preg_replace()](http://us3.php.net/preg_replace)?

Comment: Tried but couldn't figure out how to implement it properly.

Comment: Research regular expressions, that is the easiest way to accomplish this

Comment: Thanks that sorted it, I really need to restudy php.

Comment: I wrote you a regular expression that should help you get started: `http:\/\/(example.com|google.com).+`

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
$data = "<b> some text ///, test</b>"    
htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
```

Hope that helps!